# Exiting a callback function that is called within a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, callback, break

For fun, I wrote this little helper function to make looping a bit more human readable. It basically wraps a while loop and takes a callback as an argument. Now, I find myself wondering how to break out of the while loop, from within the callback function. Simply returning from within the callback won't work and I can't call break either from within the callback.

```js
const loopFor = (time) => {
  return {
    milliseconds: (callback) => {
      const start = Date.now()
      while (Date.now() - start < time) {
        callback()
      }
    }
  }
}

loopFor(100).milliseconds(() => {
  console.log("Weeeeeeee, I'm looping")
})
console.log("Done looping")
```

Comment: You cannot - userland in JS is single threaded.

Comment: Loops likes these are a very bad idea,  look into using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`

Comment: Unless you want to have some sort of return value in your callback and check that for whether or not you call `break`, you cannot do it. Still, as @Keith says, this loop is a bad idea in the first place. If you're running this in a browser, it will block *all* JavaScript execution on your page for the duration of the loop.

Comment: To expand on @Keith's comment, it's bad because it will block the event loop and other things don't get a chance to run. It's not **as** bad for Node but you should absolutely avoid this in front-end code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm aware that it blocks the thread. I mostly use it in Node, for running Monte Carlo Tree Search and stuff like that where you want to run your algorithm for a given amount of time. In the browser, I use WebWorkers to make it run in a different thread.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if Node, or WebWorkers..  Doing this is just not going to be very useful.  For starter, what are you going to use to cancel, because basically anything that's event based is now blocked,.. eg, you wouldn't be able to use a button to cancel the loop etc.   But with things like `asyc` / `await` etc, why would you even want to.?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an advisable approach but if you must continue with this approach, you will have to design your callback around providing some return value to break the while loop.

E.g

```js
const loopFor = (time) => {
  return {
    milliseconds: (callback) => {
      const start = Date.now()
      while (Date.now() - start < time) {
        if (!callback()){ //Break if callback returns false
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

loopFor(100).milliseconds(() => {
  console.log("Weeeeeeee, I'm looping")
  let condition = 1 > 5 //Some abritrary condition
  return condition
})
console.log("Done looping")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can return from callback

```js
const loopFor = (time) => {
  return {
    milliseconds: (callback) => {
      const start = Date.now()
      while (Date.now() - start < time && callback());
    }
  }
}

let counter = 5;
loopFor(100).milliseconds(() => {
  console.log("Weeeeeeee, I'm looping")
  if(--counter==0)return false
  return true
})
console.log("Done looping")
```

or maybe you can throw exception

```js
class LoopEnd{}
const loopFor = (time) => {
  return {
    milliseconds: (callback) => {
      const start = Date.now()
      try{while (Date.now() - start < time)callback();}
      catch(e){if(!(e instanceof LoopEnd))throw e;}
    }
  }
}

let counter = 5;
loopFor(100).milliseconds(() => {
  console.log("Weeeeeeee, I'm looping")
  if(--counter==0)throw new LoopEnd()
})
console.log("Done looping")
```